# Finding the minimum-maximum differennces between 2 value which are not stable in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, min, live

I want to prepare 2 excel cells shows the daily minimum and maximum of the difference between two continuously variable numbers live. For example 15,0139 - 15.096 = 0.0821, here 15,0139 and 15,096 are changable (live gold prices from different market) so difference can change.

There are 2 value on the top of the image which are starting 15 and theirs differences bottom of them.

[image]

Comment: Unclear, but maybe research `ABS()`.

Comment: Is the difference showing up always at the same cell? Is it your issue?